# Exceptions in native PHP functions

Tags: php, exception, function, native

Most functions in PHP returns true/false:

```
var_dump (is_int ("1")); // false
```

Can I configure PHP to return exceptions instead of boolean ?

```
try {is_int ("1")} catch (Exception $e) {exit ($e->getMessage ());}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `is_int` is a bad example for this. Its entire purpose suggests it *isn't* exceptional to pass something to it that isn't an integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't you just use a throw?

```
<?php

function myFunction($var)
{    
    if(!(is_int($var))
    {
        throw new Exception('Custom message about the error');
    }
}

?>
```

And the just have a try/catch block to catch your issue?

```
<?php
try
{
    myFunction(1);
    myFunction("1");
}
catch
{
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree `is_int` would be a terrible thing to throw an exception, but you could change warnings and errors into exceptions by settint an error handler that'll throw an exception with the warning or error message:

```
class ErrorOrWarningException extends Exception
{
    protected $_Context = null;
    public function getContext()
    {
        return $this->_Context;
    }
    public function setContext( $value )
    {
        $this->_Context = $value;
    }

    public function __construct( $code, $message, $file, $line, $context )
    {
        parent::__construct( $message, $code );

        $this->file = $file;
        $this->line = $line;
        $this->setContext( $context );
    }
}

function error_to_exception( $code, $message, $file, $line, $context )
{
    throw new ErrorOrWarningException( $code, $message, $file, $line, $context );
}
set_error_handler( 'error_to_exception' );
```

Not that this will not magically change non errors to throw exceptions the way you explained it, but I believe it may be just what you're looking for.

Comment: The error handler runs at the top of the stack, outside the scope of his (or any other) try {} block.  The only way to catch that exception would be with a custom exception handler.  Regardless, if you want this behavior, there's already a PHP class for it -- no need to roll your own: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php

Answer (score 1):

no, you will either have to

- use if/else statements with error handling or
- write a wrapper which throws exceptions or
- use class library/framework for that

i would go for #1

Answer (score 0):

i guess you mean functions that return false and generate a warning on failure, like fopen(). Yes, you can (and actually should) convert these warnings to exceptions, using the technique outlined [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php).